# Contribution of a single value in a Division of Sums

Tags: summation, percentages, ratio

I need to isolate contribution of a single entity in a Division of Sums as shown below. For example, find the contribution of variable `a` in the following:
(a <sub>1</sub> + b <sub>1</sub> + c <sub>1</sub>) / (a <sub>2</sub> + b <sub>2</sub> + c <sub>2</sub>)

Example with numbers:

| Stock | $ Earnings | $$ Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 10 | 100 |
| MSFT | 25 | 50 |
| AMZN | 5 | 50 |

```
Profit Margin = (10+25+5)/(100+50+50) = 20%
```

I need to break down this 20% into contribution by only AAPL for example.

Comment: For me, sentence "break down this 20% into contribution by only AAPL" isn't understandable...